# Simplify $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m)^p$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to simplify $(x_1+x_2+\dots+x_m)^p$?

Thank you!

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MultinomialTheorem.html

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee: Thanks so much for your very useful link! I have to say you did solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is a comment
rather than an answer,
but it is too much of a pain
to enter as a comment)

To see how the
multinomial series comes about,
note that

$(\sum_{k=1}^m x_k)^n
=(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} x_k+x_m)^n
=\sum_{j=0}^n \binom{n}{j} (\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} x_k)^j x_m^{n-j}
$.

Then you
see what the result is for
$m=3$,
guess what the general result is,
and  apply induction
to prove it.

Actually proving
the multinomial theorem
is a nice exercise
is induction.
Just formulating it
in a form that can be proven
is not easy.